# How to find if an array index Exists?

Tags: java

Basically I need to check if a `String` contains 2 indexes.
Based on my googling I found that I could Either use `part[0].length() > 0` || `part[0] != null` But none happen to help me here.

My code:

```
String[] parts = datareceived.split("&");

if(!(parts[0].length()>0) && parts[0] == null){
    out.print("String is null");
    return;
}

if(!(parts[1].length()>0) && parts[1] == null){
    out.print("String is null");
    return;
}
```

But here in `parts[1]` i'm getting an exception which says:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at pack.reg.pack.serv.doPost(serv.java:10)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `parts.length` (length is not a function).

Comment: @KevinEsche But that is not gonna tell if the second index is empty, right?

Comment: @akdsfjakls No, this will tell you how many elements there are, but it doesn't know if they're empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I need to check if a String contains 2 indexes

If you are using `split()` it returns you an array which you can use `.length` to check the size of the returned tokens:

```
if(parts.length >= 2)
```

> But that is not gonna tell if the second index is empty, right?

If you are afraid of getting empty string, you can `trim()` the String first:

```
String[] parts = datareceived.trim().split("&");
```

Answer (score 0):

It means split returning an array of string and its size is 1. Thats why you are getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` 
and if you want to check whether array size is 2 you can do following

```
  part.length >= 2
    // write your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when calling `parts[1]`, but not when calling `parts[0]`, we can conclude that `parts.length == 1`. Hence, since indices start at 0, index 0 contains the whole string, and index 1 in the split array (and up) doesn't exist.

--> Problem found: Your `datareceived` doesn't contain a `&`, hence it won't be split anywhere.
Solution: Hoping I understood your problem correctly (checking whether a string `datareceived` contains a value at certain indices), I wrote you a piece of code that should work.

```
String datareceived = "01234";

int index1 = 2;
int index2 = 5;
if (datareceived.length() > index1) {
    //the string has a value at index1. With the given example, this if-query would be true.
}
if (datareceived.length() > index2) {
    //the string has a value at index2. With the given example, this if-query would be false.
}
```

Side-note when using `.split`:
I found that, when using `String.split("expression")`, the "expression" part can contain regex-codes (regular expression). Therefore, if you're using any symbol that is a valid regex expression (such as `.` or `$`), it will not work (at least, not necessarily). For example, in regex, `.` means "any character", which will essentially give you an empty array.
(Note: I'm no regex expert, but "&" doesn't appear to be a valid regular expression)

Example:

```
String s = "a,b";
String[] strings = s.split(",");
for (String str : strings) {
    System.out.println(str + "_");
}
//will print out "a_b_"
```

Example (not working as desired):

```
String s = "a.b";
String[] strings = s.split(".");
//"strings" is an empty array, since "a", ".", and "b" are "any character".
```

Solution:
instead of `.split(".")`, use `.split("\\.")`